# No module named 'caffe._caffe'

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run some code on google Colab and I got this error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'caffe._caffe'
I don't know how to solve it

Comment: please show us your code. Do not put image, just copy paste code.

Answer (score 0):

For pre compiled caffe on google colab for cpu:

```
!apt install caffe-cpu
```

or

```
!apt install -y caffe-cpu
```

For cuda/gpu you can try :

```
!apt build-dep caffe-cuda
```

or

```
!apt install -y caffe-cuda
```

You can also look into these websites for details.

http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html

https://colab.research.google.com/github/Huxwell/caffe-tf-torch-darknet-onnx/blob/main/caffe_details.ipynb

Comment: I've already installed caffe module : from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'caffe._caffe'